# Core Data Row Primary key id For DISTINCT Colum

Tags: objective-c, core-data, core-data-migration

Hi I am new to core data,
I want to know the row id, for a DISTINCT Value
I written Code  Like this:

```
 NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Student" inManagedObjectContext:self.mangedContext];
[request setEntity:entity];  // Set NSEntityDescription object to FetchRequest
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"studentName"]];
NSError *requestError = nil;
NSArray*array = [mangedContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&requestError];
```

Here I am getting Student Name
Look Like this

```
{
    studentName = xxxx;

},.
```

But I need Total row or that Row Id for that StudentName = xxxx;

Please Help me

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

when you are using CoreData you are manage with objects, so there is no primary key or row id, but every entity you've created has an objectID.
So if you receive from request the entity Student, then you can take it's ID by accessing it's property `student.objectID`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                              entityForName:@"Student"  inManagedObjectContext:self.mangedContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    [fetch setEntity:entityDescription];
    [fetch setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
    [fetch setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSArray *studentDetails =[self.mangedContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error]; // Here you will get entire student table values.

// Use your NSManagedObject and get particular field value(for ex, id, name)
Student *student =  [studentDetails objectAtIndex:0];
NSNumber *studentId = student.stuId;
```